# trying to place a bottom bar along side with a responsive sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have been trying to build a website layout with a responsive sidebar and a bottom navbar --both of which have a fixed position--

I want the bottom navbar to get pushed and resized by the sidebar in wider viewports.

I have tried using flexbox utility in css and bootstrap , but that didn't solve anything. I had the position property of the bottom navbar set to absolute and i wrapped it in a container with the maion content of the page, but that also didn't work

```js
        var sideBarOpen = false;
        function openNav(){
            document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "250px";
            // document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
            // document.getElementById("main").style.opacity = "0.1";
            document.getElementById("main").style.filter = "blur(2px)";
            sideBarOpen = true;
        }
        function closeNav(){
            document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "0";
            // document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
            // document.getElementById("main").style.opacity = "1";
            document.getElementById("main").style.filter = "blur(0)";
            sideBarOpen = false;
        }
        

        $( document ).click(function( event ) {
        var target = $( event.target );
        
        if(!target.is("#sideNav") && !$("#sideNav").has(event.target).length && !target.is(".sidebar-toggle") && sideBarOpen){
            closeNav();
            }else if(target.is(".sidebar-toggle")){
                openNav();
            } 
        });

        // $("body").click(function (e) { 
            
        // });
```

```css
      html{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        body{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
        }

        /* .wrapper {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .container{
            min-height: 100vh;
            min-width: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
            transition: .2s;
        } */
        /* .container {
            margin: 270px;
            transition: .2s;
        } */

        .side-nav {
            width: auto;
            min-width: 270px; 
            /* min-height: 100vh; */
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: #111;
            overflow-x:hidden ;
            padding-top: 60px;
            transition: 0.2s;
        }
        .side-nav a {
            padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 25px;
            color: #818181;
            display: block;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .side-nav a:hover {
            color: #f1f1f1;
        }

        .side-nav .close-btn {
            position: absolute;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 15px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: inherit;
            top: 0;
            right: 25px;
            font-size: 36px;
            margin-left: 50px;
            display: none;
        }

        #main {
            padding: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: 270px;
            transition: all .2s;
        }

        .bottom-nav{
            position: fixed;
            display: flex;
            justify-content:space-evenly;
            align-content:stretch;
            background-color: #0080ffd7;
            width: 100%;
            bottom: 0;
            margin: 0;
            /* max-width: inherit;
            min-width: inherit; */
            overflow: auto;
            /* text-align: center; */
        }
        .bottom-nav a{
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 12px 0;
            transition: all 0.3 ease;
            color: azure;
            font-size: 25px;
            text-decoration: none;
            border: none;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            outline: 1px solid;
            outline-color: #6eaec280;
            outline-offset: 0px;
            text-shadow: none;
            transition: all 1250ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
        }
        .sidebar-toggle{
            display: none;
            transition: .1s;
        }

        .bottom-nav span{
            color: azure;
            font-size: 15px;
            display: block;
        }

        .bottom-nav i{
            color: azure;
            font-size: 25px;
            display: block;
        }

        .bottom-nav a:hover{
            background-color: #4355aa;
            border: 1px solid;
            border-color:#6eaec280;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px hsla(241, 49%, 55%, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(58, 174, 219, 0.2);
            outline-color: rgba(199, 42, 42, 0);
            outline-offset: 15px;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #427388; 
        }
        a.active {
            background-color:#af684c ;
        }


        @media screen and (max-height:450px){
            .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
            .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 992px){
            .side-nav{
                width: 0;
                min-width: 0;
                min-height: 0;
            }

            #main {
                margin: 0;
            }
            /* .container {
                min-height: 100vh;
                min-width: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
            } */
            .bottom-nav{
                margin: 0;
            }
            .sidebar-toggle{
                display: inline;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>UI look</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>



        <div class="side-nav" id="sideNav">
            <span class="close-btn" onclick="closeNav()">&times; </span>
            <div>
                <section>
                    <h3>Services</h3>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h3>Account</h3>
                    <a href="#">Login</a>
                    <a href="#">Register</a>
                </section>
            </div>
    
            <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark">Dashboard</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark">Shortcuts</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark">Overview</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark">Events</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark">Profile</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark">Status</a>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="main">
                <span class="sidebar-toggle" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis doloremque, natus cum nulla quos, aperiam id non enim, quo incidunt alias. Tempore mollitia incidunt asperiores dignissimos accusamus ducimus expedita excepturi!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dolorum tenetur corrupti eum sunt ut excepturi tempora magnam, quisquam doloribus, error veritatis possimus quidem saepe. Error totam facilis quod harum!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid aliquam veritatis, esse necessitatibus neque officia, error iste ipsum non recusandae praesentium odit fugiat atque, eveniet dignissimos! Earum dolore voluptates iure.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-nav" id="bottomNav">
                <a href="#" class="active"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><span>main</span></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i><span>notifications</span></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-question"></i><span>help</span></a>
            </div>
   
    
  


      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.5.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-53CQcu9ciJDlqhK7UD8dZZ+TF2PFGZrOngEYM/8qucuQba+a+BXOIRsp9PoMNJI3ZeLMVNIxIfZLbG/CdHI5PA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      



  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you have 2 options:

1.Leave the HTMl as is, and using jQuery determine the width of the bottom bar when the sidebar is open:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() > 1024){
        $('.bottom-nav').width($(window).width() - $('.side-nav').width())
    }
})
```

2.Use a container for both the side-nav and the bottom-nav and set its position to fixed or absolute. (this will only work if as I understood when the sidebar is open, the main content shouldn't be accessible and should be blurred)